# syslog-ng syslog connection broken on udp

Tags: syslog-ng

We have following remote logging configuration:

```
destination d_jenkins { network("x.x.x.x" transport("udp") port(514) template(t_jenkins)); };
log { source(s_system); destination(d_jenkins); };
```

This is a syslog-ng server to syslog-ng client communication. Occasionally we are getting following errors. Seems like EINVAL (22) is coming from write() call.

```
2016-10-19T15:12:39.393+00:00 axis-accc8e59xxxx [ ERR     ] syslog-ng[1707]: I/O error occurred while writing; fd='28', error='Invalid argument (22)'
2016-10-19T15:12:39.394+00:00 axis-accc8e59xxxx [ NOTICE  ] syslog-ng[1707]: Syslog connection broken; fd='28', server='AF_INET(172.27.0.34:514)', time_reopen=’60'
```

- Is it that network is problematic or am I missing some configuration?
- Could it be that syslog-ng server is being HUPed without our
  knowledge, dropping the connections.
- Could using TCP with keep-alive help the problem?

Comment: UDP is connectionless, which *should* negate anything about "dropped connections". Using TCP *might* give you clearer problem reports.

Comment: Whilst UDP is connectionless, additional checks can be done at layer 7 in certain apllications. TCP keepalives well, are for TCP connections. Could it be syslog restarts? How many servers are you pointing to the remote syslog?

Comment: What is the message rate of the sender host? Are there any other destinations?
Turn on verbose logging on the client to see if there are some additional messages that might help (syslog-ng-ctl verbose --set=on ), and try to increase the so-sndbuf() option of the destination. (Sorry for posting this as an answer, I'm not allowed to comment)

Comment: Rate shouldn't be a problem, it is no more than 10 message per second. I will try your recommendations.